# Allow a OneToOne relationship to be optional in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, relationship, one-to-one, option-type

I have a form responsible of creating and updating users. A user can (or not) have an address (OneToOne unidirectional relation from user).

When I create a user, no problem.
When I update a user, usually no problem.
Problems come up when i update a user which already has an address and try to unset all the address fields. There is then a validation error.

The wanted behavior would be to have the user->address relation set to null (and delete the previously set address on the DB).

There is a cascade_validation, the addess field in form (nested form) is set to not be required and the user entity allow the address to be null.

**UPDATE**

Relevant entities and forms :

User entity (Getters & Setters are classical, Symfony generated):

```
class User
{
    [...]

    /**
     * @var \Address
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Address", cascade="persist")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(
     *        name="address_id", referencedColumnName="id"
     * )
     */
    private $address;

    [...]
}
```

The address entity is classical, no bidirectionnal relation to user.

User form

```
class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            [...]
            ->add('address', new AddressType(), array('required' => false))
            [...]
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Xentia\FuneoBundle\Entity\User',
            'cascade_validation' => true
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'user';
    }
}
```

The address nested form is classical

As you can see, the is a quite classical and straightforward code. The only particular case is that address is optional. Leading to an validation error only in the case that the address was previously set (and, thus, exist in the DB and as a not null relation with the user) and the user want to unset it (all address fields are left empty).
It seems that if the related address has not an actual instance it can still be optional. But, if an instance of the address exist and is linked with the user, it can not be optional anymore.

**UPDATE 2**

```
namespace Xentia\FuneoBundle\Form\Type;

use Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\Exception;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class AddressType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add("suggestLocality", null, array(
                'mapped' => false,
                'label' => 'Locality'
            ))
            ->add("suggestStreet", null, array(
                'mapped' => false,
                'label' => 'Street'
            ))
            ->add('street')
            ->add('locality')
            ->add('postalCode')
            ->add('country', null, array(
                'label' => false,
            ))
            ->add('latitude', 'hidden')
            ->add('longitude', 'hidden');

        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT,
            function(FormEvent $event) {
                $address = $event->getData();
                if (!empty($address)) {
                    $addressLocality = $address['locality'];
                    if (empty($addressLocality)) {
                        $event->setData(null);
                    }
                }
            }
        );
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Xentia\FuneoBundle\Entity\Address',
            'validation_groups' => array('Default'),
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'address';
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your problem & your question?

Comment: The problem is that, if i try to unset the address (which should not be mandatory) when updating the user, I get a validation error. What I would like is that the address is removed in the DB and the relation user->address set to null. Which i think should be the default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting orphanRemoval on your relation

```
/** @OneToOne(targetEntity="...", orphanRemoval=true) */
$address
```

**EDIT**

I see now, you have placed the wrong listener. First of all it should be POST_SUBMIT, PRE_SUBMIT is to process request data and modify form. On POST SUBMIT you can modify the object.

Comment: Well, I was too fast... Symfony still try to validate the empty address fields which ends to validation errors.

Comment: Could you provide some code, so I can help you better? (entity, form)

Comment: Can you also include AddressType?

Comment: AddressType is quite straightforward, but I included it.

Comment: The listener is only there because the field "country" has a default value. So, if the user send the form as is, there is a validation error (the address is not considered empty as a field is not empty and the `array('required' => false)` in UserType fail). So, if an other required field is empty, I empty all the address to not have a validation error.
This is not related to my error.
Your code still leave the address in the DB if there was a previous one. Furthermore, I don't see the need to set it to null if it's already null.

Comment: orphanRemoval=true removes it from database. By creating form on an entity, the address is not null it's new instance of Address. The array('required' => false) is only on client side validation

Comment: POST_SUBMIT does not work because the validation already occured at that time.
The array('required' => false) is NOT only on client side validation because it allow an empty address when the form is used to create a user (when there is still no address linked to the user). At this moment, the user is created with a null address.

Comment: https://github.com/symfony/Form/blob/master/Form.php#L769-L784 

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#required

You are wrong. I can't help you more.

Comment: You are right about this point (the reason why I was thinking it was not is that by adding `'required' => false` allowed me to create the user without an address, the reason is HTML5 prevented me before that), my bad.
Anyway, it still remains that I'm able to create a user without an address, but I can't update a user without an address if an address was previously set (and, about that, I'm sure I'm not wrong).

Comment: Try my solution with combination of this. http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#groups-based-on-the-submitted-data i

Comment: Don't link to code, post in the answer.  Now your link is broken, and so your answer is incomplete.

Comment: @Sébastien I have exactly the same problem. Have you found a solution ? Is it possible to set the relation between User and Adress to null ? (orphanremoval should work if this could be achieved).