# Symfony forms -- removing an optional one-to-one relationship in an embedded form

Tags: forms, symfony

I'm trying to use Symfony Forms to edit an existing entity that has a one-to-one relationship with another entity that is optional.  I want to make it so that if it receives nothing for the associated entity, it will delete the entity.

Here's the gist of the code I've written:

```
 class AType extends AbstractType
 {
          public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
          {
                  $builder->add('BType', new BType(), ['required' => false]);
          }
 }
```

The A entity's association with B:

```
 class A
 {
        /**
        * @ORM\OneToOne(
        * targetEntity="B", 
        * mappedBy="a", 
        * cascade={"persist", "remove"}, 
        * orphanRemoval=true
        * )
        * @Assert\Valid()
        */
        private $b;

 ....
```

When I try binding the form with the data, even though nothing was submitted for B, it'll make validation errors that B's fields are blank, because there is an existing B entity associated with A.

I've also looked at FormEvents, but I have not been able to find a way to fix the problem that way either -- example of what I've tried adding to AType's buildForm:

```
 $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, function(FormEvent $event) {
        $a = $event->getData();
        if($a->getType() != 'Package') {
            $a->setB(null);
        }
    });
```

Even with this additional code, the errors regarding B are still appearing.

**Update:**

I think I've gotten closer, but though I can tell it's getting into the new code correctly, the B entity still doesn't ultimately get deleted, I think because despite the `$a->setB(null)`, for `$a = $form->getData();` in the controller, `$a->getB();` still returns data (i.e. editing the entity in AType's POST_SUBMIT seems to only change that data locally?)

New Code:

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function(FormEvent $event) {
        $data = $event->getData();

        if(!isset($data['B'])) {
            $event->getForm()->remove('B');
        }
    });

    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, function(FormEvent $event) {
        $a = $event->getData();
        if(!$event->getForm()->has('B') && $a->getB()) {
            $a->setB(null);
        }
    });
```

I'm really at a loss because while `$a->setB(null)` does not perpetuate to the controller, if I create a property $a->test and set that in the same location, that does perpetuate to the controller.

**Update 2**
As per comments, I'm adding some code from Entity B and the controller:

```
class B
{
/**
 * @var \A
 *
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="A", inversedBy="b", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="a_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $a;
```

As for the controller, it gets more complicated as I'm actually dealing with a 2 deep relation:  C hasMany A hasOne B.  It's also not using form inputs, but rather formatted json.  I'm using http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle/master/installation to serialize the output back into json, as well as a helper function to serialize any error messages.

```
//Where $c is either a new C entity or an existing C entity to be edited
private function handleForm($c)
{
    $json = $this->getJsonFromRequest();
    if (false === $json) {
        throw new \Exception('Invalid JSON');
    }

    $form = $this->createForm(new CType(), $c);

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    if($form->bind(json_decode($json, true)) && $form->isValid()) {
        $c = $form->getData();

        ...

        $em->persist($c);
        $em->flush();

        $response = new Response($this->getSerializer()->serialize($c, 'json'));
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return $response;
    } else {
        $response = array('code' => 'invalid', 'details' => $this->getErrorMessages($form));
        return new JsonResponse($response, 400);
    }
}

class C 
{

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="A", mappedBy="c", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, indexBy="id")
 * @Assert\Valid()
 * @Serializer\Expose
 */
protected $a;
```

A's relationship to C

```
/**
 * @var \C
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="C", inversedBy="a")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="c_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 * @Assert\NotBlank
 */
private $c;
```

And CType

```
class CType extends AbstractType
{
   $builder->add(
            'a',
            'collection',
            array(
                'type' => new AType(),
                'by_reference' => false,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true
            )
        );
```

Comment: Your question seems similar to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29333311/allow-a-onetoone-relationship-to-be-optional-in-symfony2

Comment: @mason81 The code linked to in the solution to that question is gone, so it's not really a complete answer anymore.  =/

Comment: Well that is unfortunate. I guess there's a good example of why answers should include relevant code and/or quotes from linked articles/sources/etc.

Comment: It's been a while (6 months+) since I've developed anything in Symfony, but I vaguely recall dealing with s similar problem about a year ago. I think I ended up using a FormData class and a FormHandler class. The FormData acted like a data transformer and the FormHandler processed on submit to handle if the related field was empty. I'm sure that was not an ideal approach, but it worked.

Comment: I do similar to this with a OneToOne relationship in some currently production code and it works fine. Maybe post your controller code too?

Comment: Do you have the relationship between A and B also defined int he B entity? If so, could you post the code for that? And as Richard said, perhaps also post your controller action code.

Comment: As per comments, question updated.